# Sources for Rav Pinkus's ideas on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy

We are learning [נפש שמשון - שבת קודש](http://www.zolsefer.co.il/171616/%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F)  from הרב שמשון דויד פינקוס.

Rav Pinkus typically gives concepts without giving sources. I would like to know what sources there are for the ideas that:

- on Shabbos we are, so to speak, guests of Hashem and that is the
  reason for the special enjoyment of foods on Shabbos (see אורחים בבית
  השי״ת  page 147); whereas Yom Kippur is **our** day where we create
  holiness and are prepared to give up everything (including food and
  drink) for Hashem and/or
- “it's very simple on Shabbos we meet with Hashem” page 150.

Comment: Consider breaking this up into multiple questions.

Comment: `it's very simple on Shabbos we meet with Hashem”` What exactly is meant by "meeting with Hashem"? If we know what is meantime we can better go about answering the question.

Comment: @mevaqesh You're right. I don't know is meant by "meeting with Hashem"; I'd hoped that an answer would deal with that question too. I think the answers to the two questions will be related and have considered breaking but for the moment will not attempt it. Do you want to try?

Comment: if the intent is that there is a spiritual nature to Shabbat, that could perhaps be inferred from the Bible's association of Shabbat with with "kedusha" (Exod. 16:23, 20:8, 20:11, 31:14, 31:15, 35:2, Deut. 5:12, Isiah 58:13, Jeremiah 17:24, Nehemiah 9:14). (Although perhaps that just means that the day is designated; not that it has a spiritual quality. The Zohar, however, is popularly quoted as referring to Shabbat as יומא דנשמתא. This may indicate that the day has a spiritual quality that has some spiritual effect on people. While I have been unable to find such a Zohar, the closest [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] I found was זוהר כרך ב (שמות) פרשת יתרו דף פט עמוד א 
וקראת לשבת ענג לקדוש יי' מכובד, תאנא בהאי יומא כל נשמתיהון דצדיקייא מתעדנין בתפנוקי עתיקא קדישא סתימא דכל סתימין which probably indicates that Shabbat has some spiritual effect on at least some people.

Comment: @mevaqesh I would upvote the reference from the Zohar as a partial answer.